# Unable to access the file when I use its name as a path, although the file is in the same directory

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have a file (testfile) which is defined in the source directory:

[image]

However, when I try to access it the message "File doesn't found!" appears on the console:

```
  NSString *fNameTestfile = @"testfile";
    if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:fNameTestfile] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"File doesn't exist!");
        return 1;
    }
```

So, I have to use the long path name to access the file.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `NSString * fNameTestfile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testfile" ofType:nil]`?

Comment: @Larme, it again prints that message

Comment: @Larme, and your code returns null

Comment: Is `testfile` in your bundle?

Comment: @Larme, no, it's not there when I add it in Xcode

Comment: Your executable code is nowhere near the source directory you see in Xcode.

Comment: This does not appear to be an iOS app. It looks like a macOS command line program.

Comment: @rmaddy, yes it is. I'm just learning Objective-C on that kind of apps. But I still don't understand why the files that I create (using `cmd`+ `N` not `NSFileManager in that case, they do appear), don't appear in the Debug folder (in a `Bundle`), so I can't access them using just their name

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan Command line apps don't have a bundle. Simple as that.

Comment: @rmaddy, ok thanks, now I know that ). But could you tell me what could cause the problem mentioned in my question (and in my comment to your one)? In the comment I mention that new files don't appear in a Debug folder (which is the current directory of my project, I guess). For that reason I can't access them by their name (without having to use the full path). However, when I create a new file by using `NSFileManager`, it does appear in that folder and I can access it using its name like: `@"theFileName"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following - this *should* verify your file exists.

**ALSO** make sure that you have selected this file to be included in the appropriate `Target Membership`. Having this *unselected* (not the correct target) will always give you "File doesn't exist".

If you have done this and the file *does* exist, the following will yield "Tadaaa"...

```
NSString *fNameTestFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testFile" ofType:nil];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fNameTestFilePath]) {
    NSLog(@"File doesn't exist");
}
else NSLog(@"Tadaaa");
```

Select the location of where you need to add a new file (here I choose my main project folder)

[image]

In your case, create a new `Empty File` and name it "testFile"

[image]

Then make sure it's target is correct (like you stated, it **will** be preselected).

[image]

**Then** apply the code that I have shown above (ff it does not work, there is an internal corruption with your Xcode application **or** your OS)

[image]

Comment: Well, when I create a new file (testfile), I can't select the box. Just nothing happens when I try to check the target

Comment: I've just noticed that when trying to create a file, the target for it is preselected. But after creating it, when I tap on the file in the file inspector it isn't. For that reason, I think, your code doesn't work either (prints "File doesn't exist").

Comment: I have tested this 5 minutes prior and it works as expected. There is a problem with your directory and how you are adding / creating these testFiles.

Comment: Yes, I think this is not a general problem. I create the file as usual (cmd + N) and then add it, so my project navigator looks like on the image in the question. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. In `Swift` everything works fine

Comment: There are many things that could be causing your issue... make sure the Full Path of the file is correct (where you would like it to be..) and that it's Location is relative to your project (or Group, but since your screen shot shows it is not in a group..)

Comment: Yes, I'm doing exactly that. The problem is, the file doesn't appear in a main bundle. But, when I use the files full path (from my project's folder) and copy that file (I use the name of the new file in a path above), I do see that new file in a bundle, and because of that, your code works for that file. I'm really confused. It seems, this problem appears when I create a new file